# Can someone spell out what this wget command to install Heroku toolbelt does?

Tags: installation, gnome-terminal, command-line, wget

I'm getting familiar with the terminal commands, and I came across [this](https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/linux) command to install the Heroku toolbelt:

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

Now from [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/wget.1.html) I gather that wget is used to download files from the internet through various supported protocols, and they'll download even if I logoff.

Is that right?

And I wanted to know two more things about that command :

1. I see `-q0-` in the code. What does it mean? From manpages I see that `-q` is used to turn the output of `Wget` off. But what does that mean too? And how is using `-q` different from `-q0-`
2. What is the `|sh` at the end of the command for? What does that do?

Thank you very much for the time!

Comment: I see you have several helpful answers. I would just add that you shouldn't execute that command unless you are confident you can trust the website--since you will be directly executing whatever it downloads without a chance for you to look at it. It may be worthwhile to execute wget https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh which will put the file in your current directory. Then you can examine it. (I'm not making a comment about heroku or that website, it's just a general comment).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That command actually is `wget -qO` not `wget -q0`.

It will download the file *https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh* silently (*-q* option) and anything downloaded will be will be concatenated together and written to a single file buffer file (*-O* option), that downloaded buffer will then be pipped to and executed with `sh`.

[`sh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) is a shell interpreter that will run the information that wget just downloaded.

So, in simple words you are telling with this command: download this sh file and don't create a progress output and whatever you download execute it with `sh`.

Answer (score 9):

1. Like most isolated programs started from a terminal, wget normally will NOT continue running after its parent (terminal) has been closed (via logout, etc. )
2. `-qO-` is an abbreviation of the two command line options `-q -O-`

   - q tells wget not to output status/progress info
   - O- tells it to output the downloaded data to standard output
3. `| sh` pipes the data from standard output to the `sh` command, executing the script

Comment: Thank you for explaining that -qO- is an abbreviation of two separate commands. I knew what -q did, and what -O did, but didn't realize they could be combined in that way.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a 0 (number) it's an O (letter), it redirects the output to a file, in this case (-) the standard output, so the downloaded file's content will be redirected (by the |) to the `sh` standard input. `sh` is a shell, a command interpreter that will execute the commands it receives.

You can learn more searching for **Redirections** in sh manpage (`man sh`).